# How to zip directories in android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to set a backup of my folders to a zip file. I try with this class:

```
class ZipFunctions(val context: Context) {

fun zip(files: ArrayList<String>, zipFileName: String?) {
    try {
        val fileOutPut =
            context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)?.path + "/$zipFileName"
        var origin: BufferedInputStream?
        val dest = FileOutputStream(fileOutPut)
        val out = ZipOutputStream(
            BufferedOutputStream(
                dest
            )
        )
        val data = ByteArray(2048)
        for (i in files.indices) {
            val fi = FileInputStream(files[i])
            origin = BufferedInputStream(fi, 2048)
            val entry = ZipEntry(files[i].substring(files[i].lastIndexOf("/") + 1))
            out.putNextEntry(entry)
            var count: Int
            while (origin.read(data, 0, 2048).also { count = it } != -1) {
                out.write(data, 0, count)
            }
            origin.close()
        }
        out.close()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
}
```

And use it as this way:

```
    val files = ArrayList<String>()
    val name1 = this.getDir(
        "files",
        MODE_PRIVATE
    ).path
    val name2 = this.getDir(
        "image",
        MODE_PRIVATE
    ).path
    files.add(name1)
    files.add(name2)
    val zipFunctions = ZipFunctions(this)
    zipFunctions.zip(files, "zip_file.zip")
```

But it creates an empty zip file. In-app log, I see this line:

> W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/app_package_name/app_image: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory).

Can you help me?

Comment: You are trying to zip a folder. But you should instead zip all the files in that folder. Folders cannot be zipped. Only files.

Comment: @blackapps Is no way to zip one folder?

Comment: Zip all the files in that folder.